# Amplify datastore for android implementation with complex objects

Tags: aws-amplify-sdk-android

I have an android application, which is collecting data in form of text and images.I implemented an AWS Amplify integration. Am using auth for logins, and i also added datastore for online/offline synchronization of collected data to the cloud. But i get error 400 because my item exceeds the 400kb row limit on dynamodb. After research  [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-amplify-graphql) ,  i discovered that its possible to use Amplify datastore to store complex objects like images but they are stored in s3. So the sample code that demostrates this is for react, which i have failed to implement the same in native android. So anyone have a way of implementing this in android?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Amplify only supports 'complex objects' when using the API package. This does not include the DataStore package, which handles AppSync differently.

- complex object support: `import { API } from '@aws-amplify/api'`
- no complex object support: `import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore'`

Sources:

- https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4579#issuecomment-566304446
- https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/advanced-workflows/q/platform/js#complex-objects

If you want to use DataStore, currently you need to put the file into S3 separately, and then you can store reference details to the S3 file in the DynamoDB record (i.e. bucket, region, key). This could be done with Amplify Storage module.

```
const { key } = await Storage.put(filename, file, { contentType: file.type } )
const result = await DataStore.save({ /* an object with s3 key/info */ })
```